# Central Directory corrupt error in ziparchive

Tags: c#, c#-ziparchive

In my c# code I am trying to create a zip folder for the user to download in the browser. So the idea here is that the user clicks on the download button and he gets a zip folder.

For testing purpose I am using a single file and zipping it but when it works I will have multiple files.

Here is my code

```
var outPutDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
string logoimage = Path.Combine(outPutDirectory, "images\\error.png"); // I get the file to be zipped

HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.BufferOutput = false;
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=pauls_chapel_audio.zip");


using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
     {
          // create new ZIP archive within prepared MemoryStream
          using (ZipArchive zip = new ZipArchive(ms))
             {
                    zip.CreateEntry(logoimage);
                    // add some files to ZIP archive

                    ms.WriteTo(HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
             }
     }
```

When I try this thing it gives me this error

> Central Directory corrupt.
>
> [System.IO.IOException] = {"An attempt was made to move the position before the beginning of the stream."}

Exception occurs at

> using (ZipArchive zip = new ZipArchive(ms))

Any thoughts?

Comment: Just a note if you are trying to *unzip* files: If the zip is located in your OneDrive folder and OneDrive is turned off and the file is set to online mode, you'll get the same error. Just turn OneDrive on again and it should work.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You're creating the `ZipArchive` without specifying a mode, which means it's trying to read from it first, but there's nothing to read. You can solve that by specifying `ZipArchiveMode.Create` in the constructor call.

Another problem is that you're writing the `MemoryStream` to the output *before* closing the `ZipArchive`... which means that the `ZipArchive` code hasn't had a chance to do any house-keeping. You need to move the writing part to after the nested `using` statement - but note that you need to change how you're creating the `ZipArchive` to leave the stream open:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    // Create new ZIP archive within prepared MemoryStream
    using (ZipArchive zip = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
    {
        zip.CreateEntry(logoimage);
        // ...
    }        
    ms.WriteTo(HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
 }
```

Comment: Still getting the same error. Exception occurs at using (ZipArchive zip = new ZipArchive(ms))

Comment: @ChaudhryMohsinAli: Ah. It would have helped if you'd said that to start with.

Comment: I just found out myself where the error was occurring.

Comment: @ChaudhryMohsinAli: The lesson to learn is always to include a full stack trace when you post an error. I'm still investigating.

Comment: @ChaudhryMohsinAli: See my edit. I've tested this code and it appears to work fine.

Comment: Now I am having another error as it seems. The image which I used for test when I open it after extracting the zip folder it has nothing in it. The image size is 0 bytes.

Comment: @ChaudhryMohsinAli: If this is running from ASP.NET, then perhaps the file isn't where you think it is... you may want to resolve the filename relative to the web context first.

Comment: any indicators on how to do that?

Comment: @ChaudhryMohsinAli: I'm not an ASP.NET developer, but I believe it depends on what version you're using etc. `HttpServerUtility.MapPath` is one way, but there may be better approaches now.